# Including zeros in front of an integer

Tags: swift

I have a number that I want to represent the player's score in a SpriteKit game I'm developing.

```
var score = 000000000
```

I then create an SKLabelNode with that as part of the string ("SCORE: \(score)") . So when I run it, it should currently say: "SCORE: 000000000".

However, it actually says: "SCORE: 0".

I'm making a 2D-platformer in the spirit of the classic games, so I really want the score to be formatted in this way. I see some solutions for this in JavaScript, but nothing in Swift.

Comment: `NSString(format: "Score: %09d", Int32(score))`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The literal `000000000` means the same thing as 0 to the compiler.

You can use stringWithFormat: to add [leading zeros](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html) when converting to a string (assuming you have `import Foundation`):

```
String(format: "%09ld", score)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly!